# How do I fix, Automatic provisioning failed in visual studio for Mac on developer account password changed?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have change the apple developer account password then automatic provisioning failed in visual studio for Mac.
Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to remove the certification and apple developer account from your
   `keychain` and `Xcode`.
2. Download and install a new certification of your account.
3. Add your apple developer account in your Xcode.
4. Tra again in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have the same issue but do not know how in visual studio 2019 no options